# Can i show error messages while deleting product in wordpress from trash?

Tags: wordpress

I have tried **pre_delete_post** filter to stop the product delete action. But i need to show some error there. But it only shows **Error in deleting the item.**
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bh5CW.png)

Comment: Please show your code. Thanks

Comment: function my_delete_product( $delete, $post, $force_delete ) {
 if (!$product = wc_get_product( $post->ID )) {
    return null;
  }
  return false;
}
add_filter( 'pre_delete_post', 'my_delete_product' );

Comment: I need to show an error message when deleting a product with some conditions.. Thats what i need.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.